# Read first 1000 lines from very big JSON Lines file (R)

Tags: r, json, bigdata, logfile

I'm working with a big JSON Lines file (80GB) and want to stream in the first 1000 lines to check the data structure. What worked with a sample file of 100 rows of this dataset is to use the stream_in function of jsonlite.

I've tried the following code for the 80GB file, but it doesn't work:

```
data <- stream_in(con=file("logfiles-data")[1:1000])
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a side note: Are you sure it's JSON? From the description, in particular the [tag:logfile] and your use of the word "rows," it sounds more likely it's [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/).

Comment: You're right, it seems to be JSON LINES. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `pagesize` (number of lines to read/write from/to the connection per iteration) parameter to `stream_in`?

Comment: I'd use `readLines(n=1000)` then use `textConnection()` to pass that to `stream_in()`

Comment: Thank you all!
@Schifini: So will it automatically make only one iteration when I run it once?

Comment: @Michael Bird: To be honest I don't know how to make the connection between readLInes and stream_in.